# How about the approximation capability of a convolutional neural network?

Tags: neural-network, conv-neural-network

Globally, a deep CNN is a series of compositions of linear function and sigmoid function. So how about its approximation capability?

Answer (score 0):

Given enough neurons, neural networks can approximate any function.

[Here](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap4.html) is a nice, visual proof.